# Edit Connection Strings MVC3 LINQ

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, linq, sql-server-2008, replication

We have been running one server for the past few months and it contains all the files, SQL data, and is running as our server. We have recently bought 2 more servers to use replication because our database load was so high.

We are going to use a simple  master slave replication using transaction replication in MSSQL however our methods that we use to acess LINQ entities must be changes.

For all functions that update they need to connect to the master, but all the ones that select need to query the slave.

How can we edit the connection string based on the function that needs to be done?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest approach would be;

1. Create two connection strings on the `web.config` `<connectionStrings>` section for *read* and *write*.
2. When querying data, pass the *read* connection string name to the context's constructor.
3. and, pass the *write* connection string name when updating.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using LINQ to entities, you can pass the connection string to the instance of the context i.e ModelContext ctx = new ModelContext("[edmx format connectionstring]");